# Can nodes relate to another relationship?

Tags: neo4j

Let's assume a database of workers and skill sets. Ron is a manager and plays saxophone.

```
Person:Ron <-[:SKILLED_IN]- Skill:Management
Person:Ron <-[:SKILLED_IN]- Skill:Saxophone
```

Andy endorses Ron as a saxophone player, but not as a manager. Is there a way to create an `[:ENDORSES]` relationship that links Andy and Ron's `[:SKILLED_IN]` relationship?

In other words, can you create a relationship between nodes and relationships?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relating an entity to a relationship proper in Neo4j?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972121/relating-an-entity-to-a-relationship-proper-in-neo4j)

Comment: In Neo4j, you'd want to have an additional "intermediate" node to represent something that you can relate to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wes' answer about having intermediate node is spot on, I think.  In graph theory it's called a hypernode (an edge that connects more than two nodes), but Neo4j doesn't support hypernodes natively so you'd want something like:

```
(:Person)-[:PERSON_SKILL]->(:PersonSkill)<-[:PERSON_SKILL]-(:Skill)
(:Person)-[:ENDORSES]->(:PersonSkill)
```